# Nested containerless foreach binding in knockoutjs

Tags: knockout.js

Can I do a nested foreach in knockoutjs like this

```
<!--ko foreach: $root.Students-->
 <text data-bind='text: StudentName'></text>
 <!--ko foreach: $data.Subjects-->
   <text data-bind='text: SubjectName'></text>
 <!--/ko-->
<!--/ko-->
```

Hopefully you can help me here.

Thanks.

Comment: yes you can .any issue in particular you facing.

Comment: check here for working sample https://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/27905/ . cheers

Comment: it will not work like that. it will give an error that closing tag was not found

Comment: well if you are using container less on tbody you may get the issue other than that its should work fine as given in fiddle above . please add a fiddle just in case to justify your case .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can, but maybe you should wrap this code with div if your code starts from ko markup

```
<div>
<!--ko foreach: $root.Students-->
 <text data-bind='text: StudentName'></text>
 <!--ko foreach: $data.Subjects-->
   <text data-bind='text: SubjectName'></text>
 <!--/ko-->
<!--/ko-->
</div>
```